# SwiftUI Core data + CloudKit

Tags: swiftui, core-data, icloud

I am trying to sync core data with iCloud. I have set up all the core date entities and and localy everything is working, data is saving and retrieving. When in my entity I have a Transformable object witch is picture. When I was creating Image I understood that it should not be optional, so I crossed out that check box, but when adding the checkbox of using iCloud I got error about it nod being set to default values or optional. For more context I will add inspector screen shots:
[image]

[image]

As I check the console messages I only get the logs from iCloud and core date as everything is fine -> As long as I understood those logs.
And here is my data model which completes the data requests:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject{
@Published var setReminder: String = ""
@Published var setLenght = ""
@Published var warrantys = [Warranty]()
@Published var purchaseDate = Date.now

@AppStorage("reminder") var reminder = "30"{
    willSet(newValue){
        self.setReminder = newValue
    }
}
@AppStorage("warrantyLenght") var warrantyLenght = "24"{
    willSet(newValue){
        self.setLenght = newValue
    }
}

var days = ["60", "30", "15"]
var length = ["48" ,"36", "24", "12"]

let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

init(){
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(UIImageTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName("UIImageTransformer"))
    
    container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Data")
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let err = error{
            print("Could not load data from core data \(err)")
        }else{
            print("Data loaded")
        }
    }
    self.setReminder = self.reminder
    self.setLenght = self.warrantyLenght
    fetchData()
}

func resetSettings(){
    warrantyLenght = self.length[2]
    reminder = self.days[1]
}

func fetchData(){
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Warranty>(entityName: "Warranty")
    do{
        self.warrantys = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch let error{
        print("Erros fetching default settings \(error)")
    }
}

func saveData(){
    do{
        try container.viewContext.save()
        fetchData()
    } catch let error{
        print("Failed to save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func addWarranty(setDate: Date, itemName: String, reminder: String, warrantyLength: String, image: UIImage) {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.month = Int(warrantyLength) ?? 24
    let expirationDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: setDate) ?? Date()
    
    let item = Warranty(context: container.viewContext)
    item.id = UUID()
    item.purchaseDate = setDate
    item.warrantyLenght = warrantyLength
    item.exparation = expirationDate
    item.itemName = itemName
    item.remindIn = Int64(reminder) ?? 30
    item.image = image
    saveData()
}

func deleteWarranty(warranty: Warranty){
    container.viewContext.delete(warranty)
    saveData()
}}
```

At this moment I don't understand why does my UI on different device does not update with data from iCloud, is it there something wrong with the code, the core data setup, or just in development environment meaning that in production should be working. Any help would be much appreciated.

And the container in general under target is set up, along with the notifications on 'Background Modes'

Comment: The only way to make it non-optional would be to manual create the class but who says it can't be optional?

Comment: I created the class manually, maybe I am mistaken, but when I was creating transformable object I was getting warnings from Xcode, and then I removed check mark from optional, and the warnings diapered. But not I dug a little deeper, and I need to test will it work to put iCloud container in production mode for data to sysc

Comment: If anybody stumbles upon the same problem, make sure your could kit container schema is deployed and is set to production mode, then every thing is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ValueTransformer class for the image.

You create one and you put the name of the class in the associated field in the core data model for that image attribute. Here is an example to store an UIColor data field in core data :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class UIColorTransformer: ValueTransformer {
    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let color = value as? UIColor else { return nil }
        
        do {
            let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: color, requiringSecureCoding: true)
            return data
        } catch  {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else { return nil }
        
        do {
            let color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: data)
            return color
        } catch  {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Pat